# Tuple as a return type, are unaccessed values optimized out?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++4.8

I'm returning three items from a function in the form of a `std::tuple`.

```
... myFunction()
{
    ...
    return std::tuple< int, unsigned long long, unsigned int >{ errorCode, timeStamp, sizeOfBuffer };
}
```

Since return values have to be accessed using `std::get` or `std::tie`, does the compiler optimize for unused values (g++ 4.8)?

Comment: I think the only way to know for sure is to examine the generated code.

Comment: The answer is maybe, but probably not.  Because it might be impossible for `g++` to determine whether or not the copy ctor has any sideeffects.  But in this case you're using POD, so it's def a possibility.

Comment: @StilesCrisis, yikes! That's certainly an option (one I'd prefer to avoid, if possible).  I'm already thinking that it may be more intuitive to return a struct...This just seems more fun.

Comment: On typical compilers this will only happen if the compiler does flow analysis across procedural boundaries; either with LTO enabled, or if the function is inlined, or if it has internal linkage (I think).

Comment: @AMostMajestuousCapybara What an awesome tool! Thanks!

Comment: @laser_wizard: if the concept of reading a few lines of assembly scares you, honestly you should not be trying to micro-optimize things like this. There really isn't a framework in your head for understanding the cost of a few extra instructions until you can read basic assembly without flinching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. http://goo.gl/UB7DNc

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<int, unsigned long long, unsigned int> myFunction()
{
    return std::tuple<int, unsigned long long, unsigned int>{ 1, 2, 3 };
}

int f()
{
  return std::get<0>(myFunction());
}
```

Becomes

```
myFunction():
    movq    %rdi, %rax
    movl    $3, (%rdi)
    movq    $2, 8(%rdi)
    movl    $1, 16(%rdi)
    ret
f():
    movl    $1, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: Now I understand. This does show that the values are compiled out. This is because, when `f` calls `myFunction`, it does not physically call it, but returns the appropriate value directly. Although the assembly for `myFunction` is compiled, the function got inlined and optimized in `f`. I wouldn't take this as conclusive for all cases, however, as this was only a simple example tested.

Comment: @remyabel Have you seen the URLs that gcc.godbolt.org comes up with? And it does the URL shortening automatically.

Comment: Thanks guys. Both upvoted, gonna give the answer to Stiles since he answered first. Even though he suggested I was scared of assembly. :P  Isn't that why we write C++?

Comment: @remyabel: that's what the Permalink button generates on that site. I didn't alter it.

Comment: @remyabel Would you rather have `http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22PTAEBUE8AcFNUgewK4CdQGNEBN4AtZVYAaURdAG0QENtRqA7UWAD2oFtoLYA6AKADEASwYYKyXKABEAZwAu2IYh54pgkWInwAPHORdYAPj5952AFzm9B7SLmlkDGUIDmDWHSoMXoLy4dOru50doag7JAAYo4YckoMABQAlHwA3nygmaBEeqhMZpbW3LYM9qCOzm4evojeNd4BlcGgoamgAIykAEykAMygAL4A3HwDJnagAGbJaRnZsLn5CpYuC9oADIYJEdGicbXJSSNjQA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g490%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%22%7D%5D%7D` ?

Comment: [live example](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%2‌​2%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%2‌​2%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22PTAEBUE8AcFNUgewK4CdQGNEBN4AtZVYAaURdAG0QENtRqA7UWAD‌2oFtoLYA6AKADEASwYYKyXKABEAZwAu2IYh54pgkWInwAPHORdYAPj5952AFzm9B7SLmlkDGUIDmDWHSo‌MXoLy4dOru50doag7JAAYo4YckoMABQAlHwA3nygmaBEeqhMZpbW3LYM9qCOzm4evojeNd4BlcGgoamgA‌IykAEykAMygAL4A3HwDJnagAGbJaRnZsLn5CpYuC9oADIYJEdGicbXJSSNjQA%3D%22%2C%22compiler‌​%22%3A%22g490%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O2%20-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%22%7D%5D%7D)?

Comment: @NeilKirk: for a C++ compiler to emit decent code, it needs a lot of inlining and optimization. Even trivial things in the STL take several function calls--take a look at `push_back` sometime.